# Reading from a binary file when closing and opening it

Tags: c, file-io, syntax, binaryfiles

I'm trying to read from a binary file by closing and opening it but it seems like it doesn't work.

When I change it to `wb+` and use the commented out `fseek` instead of closing and opening it does read. What am I doing wrong with closing and opening the file?

```
int main(){
    FILE * tfp = fopen("test.bin", "wb");
    char src[] = "1233 asd 333";
    fputs(src, tfp);

    char aw[20];

    //fseek(tfp, SEEK_SET, 0);
    fcloseall;

    tfp = fopen("test.bin", "rb");
    fread(aw, sizeof(char), 20, tfp);

    fcloseall;
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: `fread(&aw, sizeof(int), 20, tfp);` --> `fread(aw, sizeof(char), 20, tfp);`

Comment: Still doesn't work. @AlterMann

Comment: and `fread(&aw, ...` -> `fread(aw, ...`

Comment: Why `sizeof(int)`? you want 20 char's so it should be `sizeof(char)`

Comment: also add error checking and turn on compiler warnings!

Comment: @PaulR Still doesn't work.

Comment: You have multiple problems with the code - you're going to need to fix all of them before it "works".

Comment: Also, it worked fine with the above code when I used the seek instead of closing and opening...

Comment: You mean it *appeared* to "work fine".

Comment: LOL, I'll check all the warnings now. @PaulR

Comment: @user3121023 yeah I just saw that too in the warnings... this is embarrassing. That was it...

Comment: BTW, why not use the `&`? @PaulR

Comment: `aw` is already a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `fcloseall;` instead of `fcloseall();`